# Looking for a way to see the XML packets being sent to a web service on my server

Tags: xml, web-services, iis-6, asmx

I am looking for a tool or technique to look at an incoming XML packets posted from a vendor's server to an ASMX web service hosted on my IIS6 server.

Something like Fiddler but on the server side. Will Fiddler work that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, fiddler will work on the server side.  It will work better if you filter it by the w3wp.exe process that is hosting the web service.

But the better way of doing it is turning tracing on for the web service itself.  Depending on the version of the framework, you can enable traces through the web.config: [Enabling Tracing in ASP.NET Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb885203.aspx), or in worse case scenarios you can write or find a SOAP hook to log out the connections.  The last option works really well, but it's not a fast fix.

For an example of using SOAP extensions to hook into the messaging and do logging for you, check out the example provided here, [SoapExtension Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx).  Then you just add the extension to your web.config's [soapExtensionTypes Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5e8e7kk%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: does that trace message contents?

Comment: @John: I've never used the built in tracing.  I've always ended up using a SOAP extension to log both requests and response messages.  Does the tracing not work for the Message content?  I didn't see anything in the documentation that indicated either way.

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing that the tracing was useful. SoapExtensions have always been the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that what you call the 'vendor's server' is in fact the web service client, calling a web service on your server?

I don't know fiddler, but [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) will show you just about any and all network traffic. 
With a filter you can use it to capture all HTTP traffic between the vendor's client and your own PC. I have found it very useful in debugging.

Your capture filter would be something like: `tcp port http and host stackoverflow.com`

And as a display filter you could use: `http.request or http.response`

(and possibly something simpler, I'm a WireShark newb)